# Android Studio localhost MAMP PRO

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, localhost, mamp-pro

I have a MAMP PRO software and Android Studio. I want to access to my localhost from my Android emulator, but when I do :

> 10.0.2.2

I have a 404 error, what should I add to access to my website (that I usually access from a virtual host and that is not in htdocs) ?